# Установка MySql во время создания Instance в Ansible Aws

Tags: ansible, amazon-web-services, ansible-playbook, ansible-galaxy

Создаю инстанс aws через Ansible-playbook. Возможно ли установить MySql пакет (или любой другой) во время создания инстанса, а не так, чтобы после создания подключаться к серверу и уже после выполнять tasks для установки пакета?